# python - best way to leave only unique fields in a set of lists

Tags: python, performance, list

Consider this set of lists:

```
[
["2" , "a" , "yes" , "next year"], 
["2" , "b" , "yes" , "next year"], 
["2" , "c" , "yes" , "next year"], 
["2" , "a" , "yes" , "next 5 years"], 
["2" , "a" , "yes" , "next year"], 
["2" , "d" , "yes" , "next year"], 
]
```

I would like to take these lists and remove all "cells" which are the same across all lists:
so for the mentioned data, the result should be:

```
[
["a", "next year"], 
["b", "next year"], 
["c", "next year"], 
["a", "next 5  years"], 
["a", "next year"], 
["d", "next year"], 
]
```

The column of the "2" and "yes" were removed because they are the same across all rows.

I'm looking for an efficient way to do that, as I deal with a really large set of items.

Also I would like to preserve the order of each list (I don't care about the order of the lists in the outer list), you can assume there isn't 2 identical rows.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac the trivial way, iterating over the first row, then over the cells, and checking if the rest have the same value. if yes, removing the cell...

Comment: Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @Tetsudou it works, but not very efficient and readable, i'm sure there is a better way to achieve this using the iterators module for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `len(set(i))>1` this mean that all of the entries are not equal so you can use this :

```
>>> map(list,zip(*[i for i in zip(*l) if len(set(i))>1]))
[['a', 'next year'], ['b', 'next year'], ['c', 'next year'], ['a', 'next 5 years'], ['a', 'next year'], ['d', 'next year']]
```